# Got an error in Django view : "NoReverseMatch at /view/"

Tags: python, html, django-views, django-urls

Here are my urls :

**root urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('',include('store.urls')),
```

]

**url.py**

```py
    urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.store,name='store'),
    path('cart/',views.cart,name='cart'),
    path('checkout/',views.checkout,name='checkout'),
    path('update_item/',views.updateItem,name='update-item'),
    path('process_order/',views.processOrder,name='process-order'),
    path('view/<int:pk>/',views.view,name='view-detail'),
]
```

Here is the code for the view :

**views.py**

```py
    def view(request,pk):
        product = Product.objects.get(id=pk)
        return render(request,'store/view.html',{'product':product} )
```

Here is my template :
**template**

```html
    <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="{% url 'view-detail' product.id%}">View</a>
```

This output error :

> NoReverseMatch at /view/1/ Reverse for 'store' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$']

How to resolve this error?

Comment: This error relates to another `url` than the one you posted.

Answer (score 1):

**template**

```
{% load templatehelpers %}
<a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="{% abs_url 'app_name:view-detail' request pk=product.id %}">View</a>
```

Here we use a new simple tag namely **abs_url** (absolute url) in **templatehelpers.py** (Template tag). And **app_name** is the name of the app.

**templatehelpers.py**

```
from django import template
from django.urls import reverse
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def abs_url(value, request, **kwargs):
    return reverse(value,kwargs=kwargs)
```